# how to create a circuit to represent x^2 +2?

Tags: digital-logic

and x would be a 3 bit variable

I tried to write it as a truth table, but then I would have the inputs from 0, to 7, and outputs from 0 to 51! Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: build a multiplier first, then an adder

Comment: First  fix your logic function. It is not correct.  x^2 +2?  for x=3 does not add up to 52 combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Since the input is 3 bits wide, there are only 8 possible states, and 8 possible outputs.  The largest possible output value is 51, so requires 6 bits to express directly.

A really simple way to implement this in hardware is with a lookup table.  It only needs to be 8 locations of 6 bits each.  If doing it with discrete parts, then you probably use a 256 byte memory.

Of course this is also trivial to do several ways in the firmware of a microcontroller.  The most appropriate method depends on various constraints you haven't told us anything about.

Comment: Why 256 byte memory? 8 bytes are enough...

Comment: @Nex: Yes, you only need 8.  It will be hard to find a 8 byte memory in discrete package.  I expect 256 byte to be more available.  You only need 6 bit wide too, but probably will end up with 8 bits wide if using a discrete package.  Inside a FPGA you can use just the memory you actually need.  Note also that the LSB of the output is the LSB of the input, so you really only need a 5-bit 8-word memory.

Answer (score 2):

Since input is 3 bit variable, maximum value will be 7. So x^2+2 can have a maximum value of 51. So result will be 6 bit.

So you just have write down the input (\$x_2x_1x_0\$) from 0 to 7 and corresponding results (\$y_5y_4y_3y_2y_1y_0\$) and then obtain the expressions for all output bits (\$y_5\to\ y_0)\$. That's all.

Let me help you with the first two:
$$y_0=x_0$$
$$y_1=1$$

Similarly, you can find the expressions for remaining four. It's not that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

The truth table looks like this:

```
000     000010
001     000011
010     000110
011     001011
100     010010
101     011011
110     100110
111     110011
```

As Olin and nidhin have observed, bits 0 and 1 of the result are exceptionally  simple to implement. For the remaining 4 bits of the result you need to write the equations and simplify where possible.

In a real implementation this could be done with a 1-of-8 active low demultiplexer and four NAND gates.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the 3 bits to a 1-of-8 decoder. Assign the value that you already know should be your answer to each of the 8 outputs. Example, mentally you know that if the decoder output 2 goes active then you know the input was 010, and the answer you want to get is (2x2)+2=6, so mentally assign output 2 to the value 6. Repeat this for all outputs. Another example is output 3, we know the input is 011, so the answer we would like (3x3)+2=11. So mentally assign the value 11 to output 3. Now use one OR-gate for each final output bit. The largest answer  you can get is (7x7)+2=51 which can be represented as a 6-bit binary number 110011. So you need 6 output bits. Use 6 OR-gates for your final outputs. Looking at (7x7)+2=51 you need to output a bit in each of the weight positions 32, 16, 2, and 1. So connect your decoder output 7 into each of the OR-gates which will collectively comprise the answer 51=(32+16+2+1). Repeat that same connection between the decoder outputs and the OR-gates. The outputs from the 6 OR-gates will be your 6 bit answer. To recap, use a single 3-to-8 decoder and 6 OR-gates.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk9KJp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>